# Recursive Binary Search for Integers

Tags: java, recursion, stack-overflow, binary-search

I have tried implementing the divide and conquer technique of binary search using recursion. The code for it can be seen below. I think when the program is run, I'm getting stack overflow. If anyone does manage to find a solution, I would greatly appreciate a reason for why this happens.

```
public class binarySearch{
    public static void main(String[] arguments){
        int[] array = new int[]{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9};
        int findNum = binSearch(array, 9, 0, array.length-1);
    }

    public static int binSearch(int[] array, int searchNum, int left, int right){
        int foundIndex = 0;
        boolean found = false;
        int mid = (right+left)/2;
        if(array[mid] == searchNum){
            found = true;
            foundIndex = mid;
        }
        else if(array[mid] > searchNum){
            right = mid;
            binSearch(array, searchNum, left, right);
        }
        else if(array[mid] < searchNum){
            left = mid;
            binSearch(array, searchNum, left, right);
        }

        if(found = true){
            return foundIndex;
        }
        else{
            return -1;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried using a debugger to see how its behavior differs from what you expected?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your implementation logic is wrong and thus your code runs into infinite recursion. The correct code should be as follows -

```
public class binarySearch{
    public static void main(String[] arguments){
        int[] array = new int[]{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9};
        int findNum = binSearch(array, 9, 0, array.length-1);
    }

    public static int binSearch(int[] array, int searchNum, int left, int right){
        if(left>right)
            return -1; // We have now tried the full binary search and unable to find the element
        int mid = (right+left)/2;
        if(array[mid] == searchNum){
             return mid;
        }
        else if(array[mid] > searchNum)
            return binSearch(array, searchNum, left, mid-1); // <-- Here you were calling 
                                                             //binSearch(array, searchNum, left, right); which made your code go into infinite recursion

        else if(array[mid] < searchNum)
            return binSearch(array, searchNum, mid+1, right); //<-- you were calling 
                                                              //binSearch(array, searchNum, left, right); which made your code go into infinite recursion           
    }
}
```

The above code will return the index if the element is found in the array else it will return -1. You would also notice that I am directly returning the recursive call like - `return binSearch(array, searchNum, mid+1, right);`and not just calling like - `binSearch(array, searchNum, left, right);`

Hope this helps !

Comment: The recursive calls are equivalent to `binSearch(array, searchNum, mid-1, mid)` and `binSearch(array, searchNum, mid, mid+1)`; that doesn't seem correct.

Comment: @ScottHunter It's been corrected

Comment: What is the point of changing `left` or `right` before a recursive call?

Comment: Sorry, forgot to edit it out from OP's answer. Now its fine

Answer (score 2):

All of the solution posted so far has a integer overflow problem while calculating mid.The same bug lurked in JDK for more than 20 years https://ai.googleblog.com/2006/06/extra-extra-read-all-about-it-nearly.html

```
int binarySearch(int arr[],int searchNum,int left, int right)
    {
        if (right >= left) {
            int mid = (left+right)>>>1; 
            if (arr[mid] == searchNum)
                return mid;
            if (arr[mid] > searchNum)
                return binarySearch(arr, left,mid - 1, searchNum);

            return binarySearch(arr, mid + 1, right, searchNum);
        }
        return -1;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You're calling `binSearch` but never returning the value of that call. I think you're trying to treat `found` as a static variable in C, but there's no such thing in Java. Even if you modify it in another stackframe, the value in your current stackframe will still stay `false`.

A better way would be to use tail-recursion and directly return the result.

```
public static int binSearch(int[] array, int searchNum, int left, int right){
    if (left == right) 
        return -1;
    int mid = (right + left) >>> 1;
    if(array[mid] == searchNum) 
        return mid;
    else if(array[mid] > searchNum) 
        return binSearch(array, searchNum, left, mid);
    else 
        return binSearch(array, searchNum, mid + 1, right);
}
```

And you can invoke the method like this (`right` should be exclusive)

```
int findNum = binSearch(array, -1, 0, array.length);
```

**EDIT**: After reading the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62223595/11882002) by Debapriya Biswas, I changed the line `int mid = (right + left) / 2;` to `int mid = (right + left) >>> 1;` to avoid failing when `right + left` is greater than the max value of `int`.

Comment: What happens if left=0, right=1, searchNum=1, array[0]=0, and array[1]=1?

Comment: @ScottHunter My bad, didn't realize OP was calling it with `array.length - 1`. I've added that to my answer now

Comment: Shouldn't it be `left > right ` to confirm element isn't in the array

Comment: @Abhishek No, I've modified how the method is supposed to be called. right is exclusive, so left will never exceed it.